# Autogenerated client proxy for Wcf Data Service has entities that are missing interface that they inherit from

Tags: .net, wcf, interface, wcf-data-services

I have a client side proxy that is autogenerated by visual studio. These are using devart entity framework objects that inherit from an interface. However in the client proxy files none of the classes inherit from this interface and therefore any attempts to cast them to the interface fail. Any ideas why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total guess since you haven't included any code, but if you're referring to interfaces that data contracts returned by your service implement, these will not be available to your client.  Interfaces implemented by your data contracts aren't part of your service's WSDL, so there's no way for your clients to know about them.  One possible work around would be to share an assembly between your client and your service that contains the data contracts.  In that scenario, your client would have visibility to the interfaces implemented by your data contracts.